# convert an sql query into linq to entities method based

Tags: c#, sql, linq

i have got this query in sql server server that do what i want..
how can i convert it to linq

```
select  t1.IDHardware,h.DescricaoHardware
from dbo.ProcessoHardware t1
INNER JOIN
(select t2.IDHardware, max(t2.IDProcessoHardware) as maxVisit
from dbo.ProcessoHardware t2
group by t2.IDHardware,t2.IDProcesso) v ON
v.maxVisit = t1.IDProcessoHardware JOIN dbo.Hardware h ON t1.IDHardware=h.IDHardware
where t1.Estado=1 AND IDProcesso=1
```

this is where i am now...but i am unable to figure it past this point..

```
var ProcHardware = (from procHardware in db.ProcessoHardwares
                            where procHardware.IDProcesso == IDProcesso
                            select new { procHardware.IDHardware, procHardware.IDProcessoHardware, procHardware.IDProcesso, procHardware.Estado } into x
                            group x by new { x.IDHardware, x.IDProcesso, x.IDProcessoHardware, x.Estado } into t
                            let Max = t.Max(g => g.IDProcessoHardware)
                            select new { IDHardware = t.Key.IDHardware, Estado = t.Key.Estado, t.Key.IDProcesso,IDProcessoHardware=t.Key.IDProcessoHardware,cMax=Max }).ToList().Where(t => t.Estado == 1 && t.IDProcesso == IDProcesso && t.IDProcessoHardware==Max).Select(c => new VMProcessoChooseHardware
                       {
                           IDHardware = c.IDHardware
                       });
```

i have got this table that relates the Table hardware with a table Process.. this table is called processHardware. this table is discribed by: IDProcessHardware IDProcess IDHardware State

the field state can have 3 states (1-Insert, 2-Remove,3-Substitute).. so i can i have this:

```
IDProcessHardware  IDProcess  IDHardware State

  1                  10          1        1

  2                  10          2        1

  3                  10          1        2

  4                  10          1        1

  5                  20          1        1
```

what i want to get is get the IDHardware that were inserted but not removed from process.
so by giving the IDProcess = 10 i want to get the hardware with the hardware ids 1 and 2..

```
IDProcessHardware  IDProcess  IDHardware State

  1                  10          1        1

  2                  10          2        1

  3                  10          1        2

  4                  20          1        1
```

in the table above by giving the IDProcess 10 , it should give me the Hardware ids 2.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, and a lot of search i found this link 
http://jetmathew.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/select-latest-record-from-recordset-using-sql-and-linq/

the guy was trying something similar to what i want..
so i pick the linq query and transform it..

this is what i have now

```
var ProcHardware = (from a in db.ProcessoHardwares
                                group a by new { a.IDHardware, a.IDProcesso } into latest
                                join b in db.ProcessoHardwares on new { dt = latest.Max(itm => itm.IDProcessoHardware) } equals new {  dt = b.IDProcessoHardware }
                                select new { ID = b.IDHardware, Estado=b.Estado,IDProcesso=b.IDProcesso }).ToList().Where(t => t.Estado == 1 && t.IDProcesso == IDProcesso ).Select(c => new VMProcessoChooseHardware
                           {
                               IDHardware = c.ID
                           });
```

it still need the rest the information discribing the hardware like the serial number , or the description.
i will post here the complete query..